# Changing column content in tsv via AWK

Tags: awk, sed

I have got a table results.tsv which looks like:

```
270712  HET HET MTHFR_ABY+JUN   HET HET FSH
277916  HET HET MTHFR_ABY+JUN   HOM HOM FSH
564320  HOM HET MTHFR_ABY+JUN   HET HET FSH
```

I need to change input in $4. If $2 = $3 then will be in $4 "OK". If not, then will be in $4 "FALSE".

I tried awk

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" '{$4="OK";if($2=$3); print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}' results.tsv  >> results2.tsv
```

but it is obviously not correct :) 
I also tried to manage it with sed, but I wasn't succesfull as well.

Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to SO and kudos for posting good question)efforts + using code tags in your question) keep it up. Could you please just add sample of your expected output too in your question once and let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on shown samples could you please try following.

```
awk '$2==$3{$4="OK"} 1' Input_file
```

OR if your Input_file is TAB delimited you could add `FS` and `OFS` as `\t` too in above code.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} $2==$3{$4="OK"} 1' Input_file
```

Problem with OP's code is OP is using `=` which is NOT checking condition of if 2nd field is equals to 3rd field or not. For conditions we should use `==` conditional where `=` used by OP denotes assignment hence condition is not getting checked and output is not coming as per condition.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's very helpful and simple solve my problem.

Comment: @MirkaFamfulíková, your welcome, glad that it helped you, cheers and happy learning on this great site SO.